# How the time complexity of this code is loglogn?

Tags: algorithm

I am beginer and i am confuse how the time complexity of this code is loglogn.

```
while(i<=n)
{
i = i*i;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define the start value for `i` as *j*, then at the *start* of the first iteration, the value for `i` is *j*. At the end of the iteration, the value for `i` is *j<sup>2</sup>*.

Now the next iteration, at the end, the value for `i` is *j<sup>4</sup>*. If at the start of the *k*-th iteration, the value is *j<sup>l</sup>*, then at the end of the iteration, the value of *j<sup>2×l</sup>*.

So that means at the *k*-th iteration, the value will be *j<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>*. We will keep iterating until we reach a value for *i* such that *i > j*, so that means that:

*j<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> > n*

we can here apply the *log<sub>j</sub>* to both parts:

*2<sup>k</sup> > log<sub>j</sub>n*

and the *log<sub>2</sub>* to both:

*k > log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>j</sub>n)*

for the first *k* for which this happens, the loop will end. So that means that this will happen "between" the *log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>j</sub>n)* and *log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>j</sub>n)+1* iteration, but the *+1* does not matter here.

The time complexity is thus: ***O(log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>j</sub>n))*** with *j* the initial value for *i*, and *n* the bound in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

For n = k<sup>16</sup>:

```
iteration 1: i = k
iteration 2: i = k^2
iteration 3: i = k^4
iteration 4: i = k^16
```

So basically you can show that you are iterating log(m) times for k<sup>m</sup>, where m = log(k).

Comment: still confuse plz explain more